# I can't get code analysis rule CA2202 fixed

Tags: c#, itext, code-analysis

I have a function (see code snippet below).

I have Code Analysis enabled, and I get a CA2202 rule violation.

(**edit**: I added the close on the pdfStamper otherwise the PDF will be corrupted)

> CA2202: Do not dispose objects multiple times
>
> A method implementation contains code paths that could cause multiple calls to IDisposable.Dispose or a Dispose equivalent, such as a Close() method on some types, on the same object.

In the CA2202 MSDN page([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28CA2202%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5%29&rd=true)), the proposed fix doesn't work.

How can the code be rewritten without having to suppress this violation ?

```
private byte[] DoGenerateFinishedGamePdf(int gameSessionLogId)
{
   var finishedGameCertificatePdfFile = httpServerUtilityWrapper.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FinishedGameCertificateFile"]);

   var pdfReader = new PdfReader(finishedGameCertificatePdfFile); // note that PdfReader is not IDisposeable

   using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
   using (PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, memoryStream))
   {
      var fields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
      fields.SetField("CityName", "It works!");

      pdfReader.Close();

      pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
      pdfStamper.FreeTextFlattening = true;
      pdfStamper.Close();

      return memoryStream.ToArray();
   }
}
```

Comment: This is quite strange. I use using for disposable objects and I never receive Dispose warnings. You are receiving this for memoryStream or pdfStamper?

Answer (score 2):

Ah, everyone's favourite warning! In this instance MemoryStream.Dispose is idempotent (the current implementation does nothing) so it's not really a problem, however the 'fix' is as follows:

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = null;
try
{
  memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
  using (PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, memoryStream))
  {
    memoryStream = null;

    var fields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
    fields.SetField("CityName", "It works!");

    pdfReader.Close();

    pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
    pdfStamper.FreeTextFlattening = true;
    pdfStamper.Close();

    return memoryStream.ToArray();
  }
}
finally
{
  if (memoryStream != null) memoryStream.Dispose();
}
```

Since the PdfStamper 'owns' the MemoryStream it will dispose of it when PdfStamper.Dispose is called, so we only need to call Dispose on the MemoryStream if we do not Dispose of the PdfStamper, which can only happen if the construction of the PdfStamper fails.

Comment: The code snippet will not compile because you redeclare memorystream. If I fix this by removing the typename, I get a CA2000 error at line 5: 'call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'memoryStream' before all references to it are out of scope'....

Comment: @PatrickPeters Apologies for non-compile, copy paste error, answer updated. Hmm, there are no warnings with the above code in my VS (VS2012 using the .Net 4.5 compiler)

Comment: I forgot to place the pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, memoryStream) in my code from your code-example, and now I get 3(!!) warnings: one CA2000 at the memoryStream creation, two CA2202 on each Dispose in the finally block... Notice that I edited the original question, where I add one code row (with the close) after the pdfStamper finished its job.

Comment: @PatrickPeters Whcih compiler are you using? However, answer updated to be as per the advice on MSDN (again, generates no warnings on my machine (though apparently that doesn't mean much since the last snippet generated 3 of them on yours!))

Comment: I changed it according to your latest edit, but still get 2 CA2202 violations. One one memorystream, the other at pdfStamper, both at same row in the finally statement, arghhh...

Comment: @PatrickPeters In the latest edit the psfStamper will be out of scope before the finally block... just to check your finally block only contains the dispose on the memory stream (if not null)? May also be worth cleaning and compiling

Comment: the Close() on the stamper is neccessary otherwise the pdf will be corrupted (I tested it earlier). I'll suppress the calls for now in code and will inform this at the Itextsharp forum.

Comment: The current version would cause a `NullReferenceException` on the `return`.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the PdfStamper is disposing the stream even though it shouldn't.  It didn't create it and doesn't own it, so it has no business disposing it.

Your code did create the stream and it does own it, so it's quite natural that it should dispose it.  If the PdfStamper weren't disposing the stream inappropriately, all would be fine with your nested usings.

Your first move should probably be to file a bug report/feature request that the PdfStamper disposition of the stream be removed or at least made avoidable.  Once you've done that, you can pretty safely suppress the CA2202 violation since double disposition of a MemoryStream will have no deleterious consequences.

BTW, PdfStamper.Dispose() call PdfStamper.Close() (at least in version 5.4.0), so you should be able to remove the PdfStamper.Close() call.